# JavaScript variables are undefined

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, jqtouch

I'm writing an HTML5 app with jQTouch for mobile browsers.

I'm setting variables using code like this:

```
var activeproduct; // globally in js file
```

Then I have a `ul li` that sets the varialbe like so:

```
<li class="arrow" onclick="activeproduct=1;">
  <a href="#productClickThru">Product</a>
</li>
```

This works fine on FF but when I try it on iPhone's Safari I'm getting an undefined error when I try to use activeproduct inside a function.

Am I not setting up the `var` properly? Any help most appreciated.

Billy

As requested here is some more code (please note all list items will be generated dynamically eventually):

My javascript file:

```
var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
statusBar: 'black'
});

var activeproduct;
var activeroom;
var activearea;
var last_hash;

$(function(){

$(window).bind( 'hashchange',
    function(){
        console.log('unloading ' + last_hash);
        $(window).trigger('unload' + last_hash);

        last_hash = location.hash;

        console.log('loading ' + location.hash);
        $(window).trigger('load' + location.hash);
    });

$(window).bind('unload#productsMenu', function() {
    $('#productsMenuContent > *').remove();
});
$(window).bind('load#productsMenu',
    function() {
        console.log('Products menu loaded');

        $('<li class="arrow" onclick="activeproduct=1;"><a href="#productClickThru">Strip</a></li>').appendTo($('#productsMenuContent'));
        $('<li class="arrow "onclick="activeproduct=2;"><a href="#productClickThru">Prep</a></li>').appendTo($('#productsMenuContent'));
        $('<li class="arrow" onclick="activeproduct=3;"><a href="#productClickThru">Heavy Prep</a></li>').appendTo($('#productsMenuContent'));
        $('<li class="arrow" onclick="activeproduct=4;"><a href="#productClickThru">Line</a></li>').appendTo($('#productsMenuContent'));
        $('<li class="arrow" onclick="activeproduct=5;"><a href="#productClickThru">Finished Paper</a></li>').appendTo($('#productsMenuContent'));
        $('<li class="arrow" onclick="activeproduct=6;"><a href="#productClickThru">Emulsion</a></li>').appendTo($('#productsMenuContent'));
        $('<li class="arrow" onclick="activeproduct=7;"><a href="#productClickThru">Satin</a></li>').appendTo($('#productsMenuContent'));
    });

$(window).bind('load#productClickThru',
    function() {
        alert(activeproduct);
        console.log('Room: '+activeroom);
        console.log('Area: '+activearea);
        console.log('Product: '+activeproduct);
        if( activeproduct == 1 ) {
            $('#productClickThru > .toolbar > :header').html('Strip');
            $('#productClickThru').find('.room-label').html('Room: '+activeroom);
            $('#productClickThru').find('.area-label').html('Area: '+activearea);
        } else if( activeproduct == 2 ) {
            $('#productClickThru > .toolbar > :header').html('Prep');
            $('#productClickThru').find('.room-label').html('Room: '+activeroom);
            $('#productClickThru').find('.area-label').html('Area: '+activearea);
        } else if( activeproduct == 3 ) {
            $('#productClickThru > .toolbar > :header').html('Heavy Prep');
            $('#productClickThru').find('.room-label').html('Room: '+activeroom);
            $('#productClickThru').find('.area-label').html('Area: '+activearea);
        } else if( activeproduct == 4 ) {
            $('#productClickThru > .toolbar > :header').html('Line');
            $('#productClickThru').find('.room-label').html('Room: '+activeroom);
            $('#productClickThru').find('.area-label').html('Area: '+activearea);
        } else if( activeproduct == 5 ) {
            $('#productClickThru > .toolbar > :header').html('Finished Paper');
            $('#productClickThru').find('.room-label').html('Room: '+activeroom);
            $('#productClickThru').find('.area-label').html('Area: '+activearea);
        } else if( activeproduct == 6 ) {
            $('#productClickThru > .toolbar > :header').html('Emulsion');
            $('#productClickThru').find('.room-label').html('Room: '+activeroom);
            $('#productClickThru').find('.area-label').html('Area: '+activearea);
        } else if( activeproduct == 7 ) {
            $('#productClickThru > .toolbar > :header').html('Satin');
            $('#productClickThru').find('.room-label').html('Room: '+activeroom);
            $('#productClickThru').find('.area-label').html('Area: '+activearea);
        }
    });


});
```

index.php file:

```
<div id="productClickThru" class="page">
        <div class="toolbar"><h1 name="title"></h1>
            <a class="back button" href="#">Back</a>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="room-label"></span></li> //gets set by JS
            <li><span class="area-label"></span></li> //gets set by JS
            <li>
                <select id="quantity">
                    <optgroup label="quantity">
                        <option value ="10">10</option>
                        <option value ="20">20</option>
                        <option value ="20">30</option>
                        <option value ="20">40</option>
                        <option value ="20">50</option>
                        <option value ="20">60</option>
                        <option value ="20">70</option>
                        <option value ="20">80</option>
                        <option value ="20">90</option>
                        <option value ="20">100</option>
                        <option value ="20">150</option>
                    </optgroup>

                </select>
            </li>
            <li><textarea placeholder="Notes" ></textarea></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="submit whiteButton">Save</a>
        <!-- #new-quote close -->
    </div>
```

Comment: where is the <script> tag? in head or in the bottom of body?

Comment: The code you've posted is fine. Show us more! (the function where you use `activeproduct`, the surroundings where you declare `activeproduct`).

Comment: It was my understanding that inline event handlers like that can only call functions.

Comment: maybe it is better to wait for the window.onload event and the addEventListener() to the li click event

Comment: @jayp no, there's nothing wrong with that (other than it being an intrusive inline handler declaration in the first place)

Comment: my guess would be that the click event triggered on the anchor tag isn't bubbling up to the list-item tag. try moving the onclick to the anchor or changing the href to `href="javascript:activeproduct=1;"`

Comment: @herostwist that is almost certainly not the problem.

Comment: @wong2 script in the head referencing a external JS file

Comment: it seems to be only a problem with iphone safari browser. Safari on my W7 PC is working well

Comment: @Pointy Fair enough, I have learnt something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may well need to wrap your js in a self executing function such as:

```
<li class="arrow" onclick="javascript:(function(){activeproduct=1;})()">
    <a href="#productClickThru">Product</a>
</li>
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, I forgot to pu the javascript: in front of the function declaration.. you can check out the script in action http://jsfiddle.net/mRN5b/.

Comment: yeah thta seems to work thanks, not sure why onclick="activeproduct=1" worked for desktop browsers but not on safari iphone ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign your event handlers in js file

```
element.onclick = function(){
   activeproduct=1;
};
```

It would be a better style (unobtrusive javascript) as well, because the JS is separated from HTML.

Comment: i think you mean `onclick = function` not `onclick - function`

Comment: @Matt he could wrap it in an window.onload event

Comment: I'm not too sure if unobtrusive java script means obfuscated javascript (js you can't see). Generally assigning assigning explicitly handlers is seen to be a bad approach where ever it is done. IMHO setting an explicit handler, in a separate file, does not make it any less obstrusive. Ideally we'd be subscribing as listeners to the relevant event. If you go assigning handlers in js files, then maintainability can become a bit of issue down the track.